# Next-Auth /api/auth/error behind Nginx Proxy

Tags: nginx, next.js, next-auth

I am setting up my NextJS/Next-Auth app on a linux vm.

Nginx is the reverse proxy, passing the communications from my example.com:80 and example.com:443 urls to my internal NextJS server on localhost:3000

**When I have a Next-Auth error and the app redirects to example.com/api/auth/error I do not see the Next-Auth page or a 404 page. I see the Nginx "Bad Gateway" page.**

Do I have to add something into my nginx config file to allow this forwarding to api/auth/error ?

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen        443 ssl http2;
    listen          [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name   example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

I have configured my Next-Auth Urls:

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET = secretkey1234
NEXTAUTH_URL = http://example.com
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000
```

Thank you in advance!